# Was bedeutet "Nein, aber wir können den Reifen zusammen ersetzen"?

Tags: german-to-english

Wenn es heißt "we can replace all the tires as a package", warum steht Reifen dann im Singular?

Kontext:

> "Wir haben ein Problem. Sie sind schlecht gefahren. Jetzt haben wir
> einen Platten.
>
> Es tut mir leid. Können Sie den Reifen reparieren?
>
> Nein, aber wir können den Reifen zusammen ersetzen. Jetzt müssen wir
> zu einem Mechaniker fahren."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context I assume that “zusammen” refers to “wir”, so that the sentence says that “we” can do this together.

Comment: Warum antwortest du auf Englisch?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, ein Versehen, dadurch dass in der Frage Englisch benutzt wurde, um eine Bedeutung zu erklären, hatte ich das im Kopf.

Answer (score 4):

Die wahrscheinlichste Bedeutung des Satzes ist:

"No, but we can replace the tire together."

Der ganze Text wirkt aber sehr holprig und konstruiert. Ich kann mir keine reale Situation vorstellen, in der dieser Dialog so stattfinden würde.

Comment: Ich weiß. Rosetta Stone ist bekannt aus ein großes Werbebudget aber hat eine sehr schlecte Qualitätsprodukt

Comment: Was bedeutet "Sie sind schlecht gefahren"? Wer weiß!

Comment: Es bedeutet "you have driven badly" oder "you didn't drive well". Anscheinend stellt sich der Autor vor, dass durch die Fahrweise der Reifen beschädigt wurde. Wie das in der Praxis gehen soll, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Hallo Tilman. Ha ha! Ich habe in der Tat mal gesehen, wie unser Nachbar besoffen Auto fahrend es geschafft hat, indem er in einer Kurve auf die Bordsteinkante vom Trottoir geraten ist und schön parallel auf ihr entlang fuhr, sich beide linken Reifen plattgemacht hat. Will sagen: Es geht. :-)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Und, hast du ihm mit der typisch deutschen Redewendung "Sie sind schlecht gefahren, aber wir können die Reifen zusammen ersetzen" geantwortet?